# Setting up Spring security context / processing Google token received from Angular

Tags: angular, spring-security, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot - Angular web application. The Angular client has been configured to Google SSO using angularx-social-login library. Angular Login screen redirects to Google login screen. After the Google login is successful the control reaches back to login() method in Angular.

At this point of time I have access to Google's idToken. The control then moves from Angluar's login() to Spring Controller's login() with access to idToken.
How do I process this token so that I can set the Spring Security context?

Most of the resources in the internet mentions about Spring Oauth2 Client but not covers how a token has to be processed.

Edit:
I am also doubtful if I am going in the right direction. Do I have to set up Spring for Google authentication once again after Angular (Client side) the Authentication is successful? Is this the standard flow?

Comment: i cant help you because i have never done this, but the spring security documentation has an example application how to configure the oauth2 client to use google https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login

Comment: I am also doubtful if I am going in the right direction. Do I have to set up Spring for Google authentication again after Angular (Client side) the Authentication is successful? Is this the standard flow?

Comment: as i said, i have not worked with so i cant help, i just know that if you are sending the token to your spring backend, the backend needs to verify the token by sending it to google and ask "hi google is this token valid", and if they say yes, you send the token to a userinfo endpoint and get the data for the user and use this data to populate the spring security principal. But once again, i have never used this so i cant answer any questions.

Comment: You should in general avoid authentication in the client, since the client cant hold secrets, and i dont know but maybe you have probably a client id and secret between your frontend and google?

Comment: Yes the front end has the client-id. Client-secret is never being used. I am trying fix the SSO which was not really implemented. So I am not sure even sure if Google authentication should happen from client side or not. Anyways thanks for the input.